# Finding partial derivatives of the loss of a skip-gram model with negative sampling

Tags: partial-derivative, gradient-descent

So, after reading articles related to the skip-gram word2vec model using negative sampling, I suppose that the loss per training sample can be calculated using the following formula:

$${J_{w, c, \bar{c}_1, .., \bar{c}_n}(U, V, v) = -(log\sigma(v \cdot \tanh(\textbf{u}_w + \textbf{v}_c)) + \sum_{j=1}^nlog\sigma(-v \cdot \tanh(\textbf{u}_w + \textbf{v}_{\bar{c}_j})))))}$$

, where

- w is the goal word
- c is a list of the indices of context words
- the c-s with the bars are the negatively sampled words
- U is the embedding of the goal word
- V is the embedding of the context words
- v is a linear transformation
- sigma is the sigmoid function
- u<sub>w</sub> is the embedding of w
- v<sub>c</sub> is the embedding of a context word c
- v<sub>c<sub>j</sub></sub> is the embedding of a negatively sampled word

My question is about finding the derivative of the above function with regards to v. I've started my attempt to calculate it, but I am not sure whether I am on the right track. In other words, I will find the solution myself, I just need reassurance that this is the correct way to start.

This is my progress so far:

$\frac{\partial J_{w, c, \bar{c}_1, .., \bar{c}_n}(U, V, v)}{\partial v} = -(\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} . \frac{\partial g}{\partial v})$

$${f = log\sigma(v \cdot \tanh(\textbf{u}_w + \textbf{v}_c))}$$

$${\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} =
(1 - \sigma(v \cdot \tanh(\textbf{u}_w + \textbf{v}_c))) . \frac{\partial \sigma(v \cdot \tanh(\textbf{u}_w + \textbf{v}_c))}{\partial v} =}$$
$${(1 - \sigma(v \cdot \tanh(\textbf{u}_w + \textbf{v}_c))) . \sigma(v \cdot \tanh(\textbf{u}_w + \textbf{v}_c)) . (1 - \sigma(v \cdot \tanh(\textbf{u}_w + \textbf{v}_c) . \frac{\partial v \cdot \tanh(\textbf{u}_w + \textbf{v}_c)}{\partial v})} = ...$$
$${}$$

$$g = {\sum_{j=1}^nlog\sigma(-v \cdot \tanh(\textbf{u}_w + \textbf{v}_{\bar{c}_j})))))} = ...$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify things,
consider the scalar objective function
$$
\phi(\mathbf{v})
= \log
\left[
\sigma(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{v})
\right]
$$

Using $z = \mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{v}$,
the differential writes
\begin{eqnarray*}
d\phi
&=&
\frac{1}{\sigma(z)}
d\sigma(z) =
\sigma(-z) dz
\end{eqnarray*}
So the gradient is
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{v}}
=
\sigma(-\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{v})
\mathbf{a}
$$
From here, you should be able to derive the gradient of the skip-gram with negative sampling (SGNS) loss function.

Comment: Thank you very much, Steph!